# GDB disassembly different on exec to remote after load - not loading correctly?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, disassembly, segger-jlink

I have an `.out` file compiled with `arm-none-eabi-gcc -mtune=cortex-m3 --specs=nosys.specs`.

If I run GDB with `arm-none-eabi-gdb a.out` and do `disas main` on the `exec` I get a reasonably looking disassembly, that closely resembles the C for such a simple test.

If I then do `target remote localhost:XXXX` to connect to the device over JLink, and `load`, the `disas main` is different, not just addresses; longer even.

The `load` "succeeds" however, in that there is no error on doing so, it reports 'load size' of reasonable amount.

The disassembly after `load` does change if I change the source, but never seems to resemble the source, and is radically different from disassembly of the executable directly, which closely resembles the source.

---

My best guess is that the `load` has not correctly succeeded, what could cause this?

Or if it seems from the above that it did correctly load, why is the disassembly so different?

---

## Update:

I verified that what I'm seeing on `disas main` *after* `load` is actually what it loads (i.e. it's not merging with stuff 'left over' in memory) by manually clearing those addresses with `set {long long}0xADDR = 0` repeatedly.

So for some reason `load` really does seem to be loading something not quite what is in the source elf.

Further, one of the branches that doesn't look correct to me, directs flow to the instruction `ldr??.w r7, [r4, #4095]`. What on earth does the `??` mean - is it malformed and an invalid *type* for `ldr`, so GDB prints `??`, and therefore evidence that the `load` did not perform correctly?

Comment: Use compare command (immediately after loading) to check, if binary was successfully loaded.

Comment: @dbrank0 `remote target does not support this operation`.